# Singular matrices with index 1

Tags: matrix

If $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$, the index of $A$ is the smallest integer $k$ such that $rank(A^{k+1})==rank(A^k)$

I want to find a singular (id est $\det(A) == 0$) and non symmetric matrix $A$ using Mathematica.

Comment: Is this a question about the software *Mathematica*? Can you explain in more detail what you mean by index?

Comment: Let $A\in \mathbb{R}^{n\times n}$. The smallest nonnegative integer 'k' such that $rank(A^{k+1})=rank(A^k)$, is the index of $A$.

Comment: Nothing you have said thus far indicates that your question is related to the software *Mathematica* by Wolfram Research. Thus, I will have to put this on hold. Sorry.

Answer (score 2):

```
a = {{a1, a2}, {b1, b2}};
a /. FindInstance[ Det@a == 0 && MatrixRank[a.a] == MatrixRank[a] && a2 != b1, {a1, a2,
    b1, b2}]
```

Comment: Output omitted on purpose. Run it on your Mathematica copy